# How to print 64-bit integer in GCC 4.4.1?

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks

I am using [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) with GCC 4.4.1 and I seem to be unable to print 64-bit signed integers from my C-code.

This code:

```
long long longint;

longint = 0x1BCDEFABCDEFCDEF; /* 2003520930423229935 */
printf("Sizeof: %d-bit\n", sizeof(longint) * 8);     /* Correct */
printf("%llx\n", longint);                           /* Incorrect */
printf("%x%x\n", *(((int*)(&longint))+1), longint);  /* Correct */
printf("%lld\n", longint);                           /* Incorrect */
```

Produces output:

```
Sizeof: 64-bit
cdefcdef
1bcdefabcdefcdef
-839922193
```

64-bit arithmetic seems to work correctly:

```
longint -= 0x1000000000000000;
printf("%x%x\n", *(((int*)(&longint))+1), longint);
```

Gives:

```
bcdefabcdefcdef
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844/how-do-you-printf-an-unsigned-long-long-int).

Comment: How is the second printf incorrect? Ah, I see in the example now. Never mind. The example prints out the right value for me on Linux.

Comment: @npclaudiu - Thanks. I got it from there!

Comment: `%lld` and `%llx` are correct format directives for printing a value of type `long long` (in C99).  If it doesn't work, there's something broken in the installation, e.g., mismatched or broken libraries.

Comment: For anyone still thinking of using GCC 4.4.1 - that compiler is now over a decade old, and was 2.5 years old at the time the question was asked :)

Comment: @ReinstateMonica I worked in aerospace back then. It is not uncommon to work with 20 years old software and compilers.

Comment: @Fenikso That's perfectly fine then - I'd rather it be this way, in fact :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See if `%I64d` helps you. `%lld` is fine for `long long int` but things get really different sometimes on Windows IDEs

Answer (score 11):

To (in C99 and up) portably print 64 bit integers, you should `#include <inttypes.h>` and use the C99 macros `PRIx64` and `PRId64`. That would make your code;

```
printf("Sizeof: %d-bit\n", sizeof(longint) * 8);
printf("%" PRIx64 "\n", longint);
printf("%" PRId64 "\n", longint);
```

Edit: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850737/why-can-one-printf-in-c-not-print-two-64-bit-values-at-the-same-time) for more examples.

Comment: Those are technically formats for `int64_t`, in case that happens to differ from `long long`.  Of course there's some chance that they actually *work* on existing broken/not-quite-C99-still-yet systems. :-)

Answer (score 6):

This is OS dependent. If you're doing this on just about any GCC that uses GLIBC, then %llx works.

However if you are using mingw compiler, then this uses Microsoft libraries, and you need to look into their [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx).

This changes your program to:

```
longint = 0x1BCDEFABCDEFCDEFLL; /* 2003520930423229935 */
printf("Sizeof: %d-bit\n", sizeof(longint) * 8);     /* Correct */
printf("%I64x\n", longint);                           /* Incorrect */
printf("%x%x\n", *(((int*)(&longint))+1), longint);  /* Correct */
printf("%I64d\n", longint);
```

Answer (score 1):

longint = 0x1BCDEFABCDEFCDEF; /* 2003520930423229935 */
 you can print as-

printf("%llx", longint);

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it:

```
longint = 0x1BCDEFABCDEFCDEF; /* 2003520930423229935 */
printf("%I64d\n", longint);
printf("%I64x\n", longint);
```

Prints:

```
2003520930423229935
1bcdefabcdefcdef
```

Thanks @npclaudiu!