# Make a Integer from 6 bytes or more using C++

Tags: c++, integer, byte-shifting

I am new in `C++` programming. I am trying to implement a code through which I can make a single integer value from `6` or more `individual bytes`.

I have Implemented same for `4 bytes` and it's working

**My Code for 4 bytes:**

```
char *command = "\x42\xa0\x82\xa1\x21\x22";
__int64 value;
value = (__int64)(((unsigned char)command[2] << 24) + ((unsigned char)command[3] << 16) + ((unsigned char)command[4] << 8) + (unsigned char)command[5]);
printf("%x  %x  %x  %x  %x",command[2], command[3], command[4], command[5], value);
```

Using this Code the value of `value` is `82a12122` but when I try to do for 6 byte then the result was is wrong.

**Code for 6 Bytes:**

```
char *command = "\x42\xa0\x82\xa1\x21\x22";
__int64 value;
value = (__int64)(((unsigned char)command[0] << 40) + ((unsigned char)command[1] << 32) + ((unsigned char)command[2] << 24) + ((unsigned char)command[3] << 16) + ((unsigned char)command[4] << 8) + (unsigned char)command[5]);
printf("%x  %x  %x  %x  %x  %x  %x", command[0], command[1], command[2], command[3], command[4], command[5], value);
```

The output value of `value` is `82a163c2` which is wrong, I need `42a082a12122`.
So can anyone tell me how to get the expected output and what is wrong with the `6 Byte` Code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `(unsigned char)command[0] << 40`, your unsigned char, will be promote to `int` which has less byte than `int64_t` in your case.

Comment: don't use `%x`, for chars use `%hhx`, for int64 `%llx` in printf

Comment: You have to cast it to `_int64` before shifting.

Comment: @IlyaBursov: Technically, if you want to be careful, [you'd use the `inttypes.h` macros like `PRIx64`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6850853/364696) rather than guessing at the correspondence between relative width prefixes like `ll` and the fixed bit width types. Or since it's C++, you'd just use `iostream` with `std::cout` and avoid the issue entirely.

Comment: Is this actually C++? looks like low-level C to me.

Comment: You should declare `command` as `uint8_t const * const` because `char` may be signed or unsigned (or char) as defined by the compiler.

Comment: @Walter: The OP tagged it C++, so I'm assuming they're *able* to use C++ features, even if the code doesn't use any as written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cast each byte to a sufficiently large unsigned type before shifting. Even after integral promotions (to `unsigned int`), the type is not large enough to shift by more than 32 bytes (in the usual case, which seems to apply to you).

See here for demonstration: https://godbolt.org/g/x855XH

```
unsigned long long large_ok(char x)
{
    return ((unsigned long long)x) << 63;
}

unsigned long long large_incorrect(char x)
{
    return ((unsigned long long)x) << 64;
}


unsigned long long still_ok(char x)
{
    return ((unsigned char)x) << 31;
}

unsigned long long incorrect(char x)
{
    return ((unsigned char)x) << 32;
}
```

---

In simpler terms:

The shift operators promote their operands to `int`/`unsigned int` automatically. This is why your four byte version works: `unsigned int` is large enough for all your shifts. However, (in your implementation, as in most common ones) it can only hold 32 bits, and the compiler will not automatically choose a 64 bit type if you shift by more than 32 bits (that would be impossible for the compiler to know).

If you use large enough integral types for the shift operands, the shift will have the larger type as the result and the shifts will do what you expect.

If you turn on warnings, your compiler will probably also complain to you that you are shifting by more bits than the type has and thus always getting zero (see demonstration).

(The bit counts mentioned are of course implementation defined.)

---

A final note: Types beginning with double underscores (`__`) or underscore + capital letter are reserved for the implementation - using them is not technically "safe". Modern C++ provides you with types such as `uint64_t` that should have the stated number of bits - use those instead.

Comment: Still getting the same answer, My expression is value = (((unsigned long long)command[0] << 40) + ((unsigned char)command[1] << 32) + ((unsigned char)command[2] << 24) + ((unsigned char)command[3] << 16) + ((unsigned char)command[4] << 8) + (unsigned char)command[5]);

Comment: You are missing it for the 32 bit shift. That one is too large too. But really, you should do it for all of them for consistency. Also mind my edit.

Comment: Can I cast all of them with unsigned long long sir?

Comment: Yes, or just use `uint64_t`. It's shorter to type/read and guaranteed to be 64 bits long, unlike `unsigned long long`, which is not _guaranteed_ to be (but usually is) 64 bits.

Comment: Sir, I have heard that endianess is necessary when doing byte shifting can you please explain a bit about that.

Comment: @ChandrapalSinghJhala Sorry, that would be off-topic for this question. If, after investigating that problem yourself, you cannot find a way that works, you are welcome to ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

Your shift overflows bytes, and you are not printing the integers correctly.

This code is working:
(Take note of the print format and how the shifts are done in `uint64_t`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    const unsigned char *command = (const unsigned char *)"\x42\xa0\x82\xa1\x21\x22";
    uint64_t value=0;
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        value <<= 8;
        value += command[i];
    }
    printf("%x  %x  %x  %x  %x  %x  %llx",
             command[0], command[1], command[2], command[3], command[4], command[5], value);
}
```

Comment: @MaxLanghof fixed to `uint64_t`